# Page/paragraph references within quotations

Tags: punctuation

I work as a proofreader in a patent firm and am struggling to find a concrete answer to a punctuation problem I see almost every day.

It's probably not a situation that pops up commonly in regular English, but a patent consists of a list of claims (succinctly written), the content of which is backed up by a more verbose "detailed description". When a patent examiner rejects a patent application, he/she will often quote the claims of a similar patent that exists, and include references to the supporting paragraphs in the detailed description of that patent.

My question is, as the references to the support paragraphs are not actually written in the original claims being quoted, how is the best way to include the references within a long quote. My work consists of reviewing documents which have been translated from Korean, and this doesn't seem to be an issue in Korean, but the following example looks a little off to me:

> The features of the invention of the application correspond to the
>   features of the cited reference of "a frame supporting a net and
>   positioning the net as a spaced relationship from a vehicle and a
>   structure (see paragraphs [0044], [0045]; and Fig. 3); and hard points
>   disposed at least at select nodes (see paragraph [0077]); the hard
>   points including: a multi-sided body with a cavity therein behind a
>   front face thereof (see paragraph [0021]), and a plug received in the
>   cavity locking a net node in the cavity and securing the hard point to
>   the net node in a pivotable fashion (see paragraph [0021]).”

In this case, the parts like "(see paragraphs [0044], [0045]; and Fig. 3)" have been added by the examiner, but are not in the original document being quoted.

I'd considered putting the information is square brackets, but as our company style guide insists on square brackets being used for paragraph references, that would look a little messy. I'm wondering whether italicizing the paragraph references would be acceptable? i.e.

> The features of the invention of the application correspond to the
>   features of the cited reference of "a frame supporting a net and
>   positioning the net as a spaced relationship from a vehicle and a
>   structure *(see paragraphs [0044], [0045]; and Fig. 3)*; and hard
>   points disposed at least at select nodes *(see paragraph [0077])*; the
>   hard points including: a multi-sided body with a cavity therein behind
>   a front face thereof *(see paragraph [0021])*, and a plug received in
>   the cavity locking a net node in the cavity and securing the hard
>   point to the net node in a pivotable fashion *(see paragraph
>   [0021])*.”

Or, whether simply breaking it down into multiple mini quotes like this would be best? (I'd prefer to avoid this as long examples can often include more than 25 such references)

> The features of the invention of the application correspond to the
>   features of the cited reference of "a frame supporting a net and
>   positioning the net as a spaced relationship from a vehicle and a
>   structure" (see paragraphs [0044], [0045]; and Fig. 3); "hard points
>   disposed at least at select nodes" (see paragraph [0077]); "the hard
>   points including: a multi-sided body with a cavity therein behind a
>   front face thereof" (see paragraph [0021]); and "a plug received in
>   the cavity locking a net node in the cavity and securing the hard
>   point to the net node in a pivotable fashion" (see paragraph [0021]).

Thanks a lot for any suggestions provided!

Comment: I think this primarily opinion-based and likely will be closed on that basis, but I like the italics.  The thing I don't like particularly is the "...correspond to the features of the cited reference ***of***"  seems like it would read better as "...correspond to the features of the cited reference, ***in particular***: "a frame supporting a net... (*see para..*)"

Comment: Sorry. If the parenthetical paragraph (and figure) references are not part of the quoted text, they need to go outside the quotes *unless* your company style says otherwise.

Comment: This is off-topic. You might like to try the [writers.se] site.

Comment: The italics seem helpful.  I just wish you could use an outline style and get away from the paragraph format.

Comment: Apologies for posting an off-topic question here, but I really appreciate the advice! Thank you.